# Best way to handle cross server php includes

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

This is a 2 part question...

1) Does file_get_contents create server load?  I am using it a solid 3+ times in my blogs sidebar to pull out advertisements through my blog network, but now the network is slowing down.   I want to make sure that's not the cause.

2) What IS the best way to handle cross-server includes?  Like I said above, I am using file_get_contents, and probably doing it in a VERY poor way.   Looking at some of my code, I'll see:

```
<?
$c = file_get_contents("http://www.url.com/includes/include1.php");
echo ($c);
?>  
<?
$c = file_get_contents("http://www.url.com/includes/include2.php");
echo ($c);
?>
```

I understand right now that's sloppy because it's opening and closing php when you don't need to, plus it's putting two different URL's under the same variable.  That makes me wonder how it even works at this point.

Anyway, I'm looking for the best solution to my cross-server include problem which will hopefully lower the drag on my server under heavier loads.

Thank yo!

Comment: Off-site includes should be shunned. Not only are they slow because the server has to reach out over the network, they're also opening huge attack vectors into your application. What exactly are you using them for? There's probably a better way.

Comment: If you are just embedding content, then consider an iframe or jQuery .load() to insert the text.

Comment: OP here - To Deceze, I am just including stuff that is repetitive through my network.  IE, if I have a top menu linking my network together, or an RSS box, or an ad square.  This way if I have to make a small change, I simply change one file instead of like 50+.  If there is a better way, I'll jump all over that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not allow cross-server includes. What would be stopping someone other than you from reading the contents of your PHP files?

As for your original question: If you are concerned about responsiveness, then load your advertisements via Ajax (I recommend jQuery). That way the real content will load quickly with the ads arriving shortly afterwards.

Another option to consider would be caching your ads somehow.

Comment: Right.. right now my php files are very harmless, in theory they should be text files, but you're right.   Do you know of a good way to update multiple pages at once, for say advertisements and such?   Thanks!

Comment: Are your advertisements on the same server as the page? Or an external domain, like if you were using Google AdWords?

Answer (score 1):

A far better way is to have a seperate script fetch that information and then cache it in a file on your server. Then serve up that cached file. A cron job can refresh the cache every now and then, and your site's performance is completely independent of the ad server's availability. As it stands now, if the ad server is down, your script will hang until the request times out, and your user is left standing at a blank screen for eternity.

Comment: Well it's all part of the same server, but you're right, when I expand I do plan on having multiple servers and will eventually lead to that problem.   Could you point me in the direction how to do that?